Pipe raw video to ffmpeg, output dash, play on web using dash.js
I am trying to live stream a sequence of images generated at real time to a web page.
I am using ffmpeg with the pipe: input and streaming raw bitmaps as follows:
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 1280x720 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i pipe: ...
(Note #1: If I specify a video file as output, e.g. out.mp4, it generates a valid file)
I am then using ffmpeg to output the video in DASH format as follows:
... -i pipe: -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -f dash my.mpd
Then I use the following html page to display it:
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dash.js Rocks</title>
        <style>
            video {
                width: 1280px;
                height: 720px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <video id="videoPlayer" controls autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/v3.1.0/dash.all.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var url = "/my.mpd";
                var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
                player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
                player.play();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

My problem is, there is a latency of 20-40 seconds from the real time image to the displayed image. And nothing I have tried gets rid of that.
(Note #2: When using ffplay my.mpd to show the video I also get the same delay)
I've tried:

-ldash 1
-streaming 1
-target_latency 0
-index_correction 1

And many many more options over the past 2 weeks.
